# How to track RSS feed useage / views?

Tags: rss, tracking

What's the best way to track how many times items in your RSS have been accessed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RSS is served from a webserver, the server logs would be the obvious place to gather statistics from. There are numerous packages for parsing and interpreting webserver logs.

[AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a popular (free) package, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) keeps a fairly comprehensive list.

Answer (score 1):

If you serve your feeds through something like [FeedBurner](http://www.feedburner.com/) then you can also get stats from there including clicks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Analytics, but you would need a service to make the correct requests to the Google Analytics API or redirect to it. There are two APIs you can use:

- the __utm.gif "API"
- the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) API

To use the later (you need Universal Analytics), which is way better in my opinion, you would need to make a request or redirect to something like:

`http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=<randomnumber>&t=pageview&dh=<domainname>&cid=<unique-client-uuid>&tid=<propertyid>&v=1dp=<path>`

Where:

- `<randomnumber>` is a random number to avoid caches (especially if you do redirects)
- `<domainname>` is the domain name you see in your tracking code
- `<propertyid>` is the property id you see in your tracking code (eg: UA-123456)
- `<path>` is the path to the page you want to register the pageview for. Note that it must be quoted. Eg, for `/path/to/page` you would need to send `%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage`

I've implemented a simple redirector service that does exactly that [here](https://github.com/ionelmc/t.ionelmc.ro) (explained at length [here](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2013/11/01/pelican-feed-analytics/))

If you're stuck with the Classic Analytics then you would need to use [nojsstats](http://nojsstats.blogspot.com/) or [the older implementation](https://github.com/ionelmc/t.ionelmc.ro/blob/d92c778a59a47984306a92e12136b9e439c9f707/views.py)