# Use Google Analytics on the RSS Feed page

Tags: asp.net, rss, google-analytics

I have an RSS feed page which I want to track using Google Analytics. I tried adding the analytics code in .aspx as well as in the .aspx.cs page but for some reason when I check the RSS feed page's source, I don't see the analytics code in there. 
The analytics javascript code works on all the other pages of the website.

Is it that RSS page doesn't allow javascript? Is there any way I can use google analytics to track the RSS feeds page itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track RSS feed useage / views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451363/how-to-track-rss-feed-useage-views)

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117958/track-views-of-rss-feeds-in-newsreaders